# Count value from database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below data.

```
ID        UserID        Grade
1           1             A
2           1             A
3           1             a
4           1             a
5           1             b
6           1             C
7           1             c
8           1             b
9           2             b
10          2             C
11          1             b
12          2             A
```

I want below results.

```
RunningNumber UserID         Result         Count
1                1             a              4
2                1             b              1
3                1             c              2
4                1             b              2
5                2             b              1
6                2             c              1
7                2             a              1
```

The result will count column Grade (case insensitive) and must be group by UserID.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a basic `group by` query.  If you are using the SQL language, you should know the very basics.

Comment: You have two times Result=b for UserID=1.

Answer (score 3):

Use as below

```
 SELECT UserID, Grade, COUNT(ID) AS Count 
     FROM Table1
 GROUP BY UserID,Grade;
```

Updated

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY Grade) AS RunningNumber , 
   UserID, Grade, COUNT(ID) AS Count 
     FROM Table1
 GROUP BY UserID,Grade;
```

Comment: Where is the `RunningNumber`?

Comment: i think `OVER (ORDER BY  UserID,Grade)` is more appropriate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It can be but I think, When we are selecting aggregate then it is sufficient.

Comment: This is not my result. If you see my result, UserID=1 will have Result=b 2 records. But your answer will have only 1 record.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Group by & count

```
SELECT  ID ,UserID,Grade 
COUNT(ID) FROM Tabel
GROUP BY Grade,UserID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` for the `RunningNumber`, `COUNT(*)OVER` for the count per ID and `ROW_NUMBER` to take only the first row:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
       RunningNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UserID, Grade),
       UserID, Result = Grade,        
       [Count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, Grade),
       RowNum  = ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, Grade ORDER BY ID)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT RunningNumber, UserID, Result,  [Count]
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1779a/5/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_not="SELECT count(status) AS sum FROM `user_leave_details`WHERE     (status='2' Or status='3') AND user_id_no='$user_id_no'";
$result=mysqli_query($bd,$query_not);
while($arr=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
$sum=$arr['sum'];
}

connect.php
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$bd=mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
?>
```